# Randomly select a line from text file without selecting the same line twice VBA

Tags: vba, random, text, powerpoint

I have a text file with questions, one per line. I want powerpoint to randomly select a line from the file and put that line into a label. I would also like to make sure that each line would only be used once. If there is no easy way of going about this, maybe a way to delete the line that was selected from the text file. I found some code online but it won't do what I want (not using the same line twice).

Comment: Please post the code and point out exactly what it is doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub do_file()
  Dim myArray

  Open [YOUR TEXT FILE HERE] For Input As #1
    fileinfo = Input(LOF(1), #1)
  Close #1
  myArray = Split(fileinfo, vbCrLf)

  myArray = ShuffleArray(myArray)

  For i = 0 To UBound(myArray)
    [YOUR LABEL HERE] = myArray(i)
  Next i

End Sub

Function ShuffleArray(OrigArray As Variant) As Variant
  Dim RandNum As Long
  Dim Holder As Variant
  Dim ReturnArray() As Variant

  ReDim ReturnArray(LBound(OrigArray) To UBound(OrigArray))
  For i = LBound(OrigArray) To UBound(OrigArray)
    ReturnArray(i) = OrigArray(i)
  Next i
  For i = LBound(OrigArray) To UBound(OrigArray)
    RandNum = Int((UBound(OrigArray) - LBound(OrigArray)) * Rnd + LBound(OrigArray))
    If i <> RandNum Then
        Holder = ReturnArray(i)
        ReturnArray(i) = ReturnArray(RandNum)
        ReturnArray(RandNum) = Holder
    End If
  Next i
  ShuffleArray = ReturnArray

End Function
```

This will read the file put each line into an array and then will Shuffle the array. It will then loop through the shuffled array which is where you will need to include your labels for output of the questions.